# I'm trying to generate a pdf from a HTML with a javascript in it via a java spring endpoint

Tags: javascript, java, spring, pdf-generation

The code works and generates the pdf, but only the static html part and not the javascript generated chart:

```
<!-- report.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script> 

</head>
<p>this is chart</p>
<body>
<div style="width: 800px; height: 400px;">
    <canvas id="barChart"></canvas>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/ChartInitialization.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the script, which is working fine with the HTML when opened in the browser and it generates the chart correctly:

```
var barData = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];


var barChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('barChart').getContext('2d'), {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Label 1', 'Label 2', 'Label 3', 'Label 4', 'Label 5'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Bar Chart',
            data: barData,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
});
```

Here is the controller code:

```
package com.example.chartjs.controllers;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.context.Context;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/pdf")
public class PDFController {

    @Autowired
    private TemplateEngine templateEngine;

    @GetMapping("/generate")
    public void generatePDF(HttpServletResponse response) {
        Context context = new Context();


        String htmlContent = templateEngine.process("report", context);

        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try {
            ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
            renderer.setDocumentFromString(htmlContent);
            renderer.layout();
            renderer.createPDF(os, false);
            renderer.finishPDF();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=report.pdf");

        try (OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream()) {
            os.writeTo(out);
            os.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if the javascript code is executing after the generation of the pdf, or is there some other issue.

Comment: Can you elaborate more please how can I introduce a delay from outside for the javascript to be executed before the pdf?